# Ceph, boto3: alive link checking

Tags: boto3, boto, ceph

There is a problem with alive link checking. I think that the best way to check link lays through HTTP HEAD method. But when i generate link with [Boto3.generate_presigned_url](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.generate_presigned_url) in parametr HttpMethod (string) i couldn't set "HEAD, GET". So i have chance only for checking link or getting object by link, not both.

How chould i check alive link?

Answer (score 0):

You can only specify one HTTP method (HEAD, GET, ...) when creating a presigned URL. This is a problem for software that performs a HEAD request before a GET request.

The only solution that I have seen is to implement a proxy in front of S3. When it sees a presigned URL for a HEAD request, it allows it using the AWS SDK. However, this defeats most of the benefits of S3.